# splitting div into multiple divs in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to make the columns and rows in the mainContent div but the problem is the it is getting out of the mainContent after 2-3 clicks. I want it to remain inside and should create equally sized columns and rows inside of it. here is my code.

```js
var test2 = document.getElementById('btn');
test2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('clicked');
  var contain = document.getElementById('contentArea'); // for selecting id
  var newGriding = document.createElement('div');
  newGriding.setAttribute('id', 'grid');
  contain.appendChild(newGriding);
});
```

```css
#contentArea {
  background-color: #babab3;
  height: 74vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#grid {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: 5px dashed #aba4a4;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentArea">
</div>
<button id="btn">
    create
</button>
```

Comment: here is my pencode : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpaXjv

Comment: If you want the contents to be scrolled, simply add `overflow: auto` to the `#contentArea`.

Comment: You want the divs to resize the more there are? Then you need to dynamically change the `height: 100%;
  width: 50%;`

Comment: Issue: On 3rd click, you have 3 divs with `50%` width. Thats total 150% width. What I'd suggest you is to count the number of divs and based on that, assign new widths to all. So on 3rd, it would be `33.33%` and on 4th, it would be `25%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using fixed height for the appending element.

You should resize the element after every click using some logic or you can use the display of your `parent` as `flex` and `flex wrap` true.

```js
var test2 = document.getElementById('btn');
test2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var contain = document.getElementById('contentArea'); // for selecting id
  var newGriding = document.createElement('div');
  newGriding.setAttribute('id', 'grid');
  contain.appendChild(newGriding);
});
```

```css
#contentArea {
  background-color: #babab3;
  height: 74vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#grid {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: 5px dashed #aba4a4;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentArea">
</div>
<button id="btn">create</button>
```

or

```js
var test2 = document.getElementById('btn');
test2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var contain = document.getElementById('contentArea'); // for selecting id
  var newGriding = document.createElement('div');
  newGriding.setAttribute('id', 'grid');
  contain.appendChild(newGriding);
  resizeDiv();
});
var maxInRow = 2;

function resizeDiv() {
  var allGrids = document.querySelectorAll("#contentArea > #grid");

  var width = 100 / maxInRow;
  var len = allGrids.length;
  var colNo = Math.floor(len / maxInRow);
  colNo = colNo - (len / maxInRow) == 0 ? colNo : colNo + 1;

  var height = 100 / colNo;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    allGrids[i].style.width = width + "%";
    //"calc(" + width + "% - 10px)"; --- if doesn't want box-sizing to be borderbox
    allGrids[i].style.height = height + "%";
    //"calc(" + height + "% - 10px)"; --- if doesn't want box-sizing to be borderbox
    //reduce the size of box which increased due to outline
  }
}
```

```css
#contentArea {
  background-color: #babab3;
  height: 74vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#grid {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 5px dashed #aba4a4;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentArea">
</div>
<button id="btn">
    create
</button>
```

Comment: Yes maybe I have not tested it let me correct it. It was just the reference of logic how it should be implemented.